# Xcode says "Your maximum App ID limit has been reached" and "Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles"

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id, bundle-identifier

For several weeks I have been writing apps in Xcode (11.5 on macOS Catalina 10.15.5) and successfully running them on my iPhone 11 Pro Max (iOS 13.5.1).  At this point I'm interested only in development, not in the app store, and I belong to my own Personal Team.

Then I tried to run Apple's Augmented Reality project at
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/tracking_and_visualizing_planes

After trying to run this project, I suddenly find that I can no longer run my own projects on my phone.  Xcode now gives me the following two error messages:

> Communication with Apple failed: Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days.

> No profiles for 'edu.myschool.NameOfMyApp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'edu.myschool.NameOfMyApp'.

I already have a workaround, but it's silly and arbitrary.  When I create a new Xcode project, I select the blue project file at the top of the Project Navigator, go to "Signing & Capabilities", and change the bundle identifier from edu.myschool.NameOfMyApp to edu.myschool.NameOfOldApp, where NameOfOldApp is the name of an app I had successfully run before my unlucky experiment with Apple's Augmented Reality project.  How can I change things back to the way they originally were?  In other words, how can I run my apps on my phone again without having to change the bundle identifier?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have an account with the developer program and are limited to juste a few apps. You can either ask Apple to clean your existing profiles and bundle ids, but you may end in a similar situation soon. Or you can pay for the developer program (99 USD per year), that way you can manage all your profiles, certificates, bundles, etc.